# preg_replace is unable to find and replace the string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am using these two function to extract attributes of html tags but it is not working as i thought so. 
What i want is that they should extract the attribute and replace it with SANITIZED

or

they entirely remove all given attributes from the tag.

```
public function sanitizeHTML($inputHTML, $allowed_tags = array('<h2>', '<h3>', '<p>', '<br>', '<b>', '<i>', '<a>', '<ul>', '<li>', '<blockquote>', '<span>', '<code>', '<img>')) {
    $_allowed_tags = implode('', $allowed_tags);
    $inputHTML = strip_tags($inputHTML, $_allowed_tags);
    return preg_replace('/#<(.*?)>#ise/', "'<' . $this->removeBadAttributes('\\1') . '>'", $inputHTML);
}

public function removeBadAttributes($inputHTML) {
    $bad_attributes = 'onclick|ondblclick|onblur|onfocus|onerror|'.'mouseleave|mouseenter|onmousedown|onmouseup|onmousemove|onmouseout|onmouseover|' . 'onkeypress|onkeydown|onkeyup|javascript:';
    return stripslashes(preg_replace("/#($bad_attributes)(\s*)(?==)#ise/",'SANITIZED', $inputHTML));
}
```

**Please Answer me in Detail. I don't know much about reg exp**

Comment: **No, i tried your reg exp but nothing changed**

Comment: Please do **not** use the `e` modifier but use `preg_replace_callback` instead!

Comment: @AbdulRehmanKhan: Do not comment in full-bold.

Comment: @ Rajat i tried in both function but i won't work

Comment: have you debugged $inputHTML in removeBadAttributes? You are sure it is not empty? Please add the $inputHTML.

Comment: Aren't you receiving an error message? Also it's always good to give a sample string to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems to be in wrong flavor or maybe it's not valid at all. Also, try to do not use the `e` modifier, like @ThiefMaster said.

Fixed code is:

```
public function sanitizeHTML($inputHTML, $allowed_tags = array('<h2>', '<h3>', '<p>', '<br>', '<b>', '<i>', '<a>', '<ul>', '<li>', '<blockquote>', '<span>', '<code>', '<img>')) {
    $_allowed_tags = implode('', $allowed_tags);
    $inputHTML = strip_tags($inputHTML, $_allowed_tags);
    preg_match_all('/<(.*?)>/is', $inputHTML, $tags);
    foreach($tags[1] as $i => $tag ){
        $sanitized_tags[$i] = $this->removeBadAttributes($tag);
    }
    return str_replace($tags[1], $sanitized_tags, $inputHTML);
}

public function removeBadAttributes($inputHTML) {
    $bad_attributes = 'onclick|ondblclick|onblur|onfocus|onerror|'.'mouseleave|mouseenter|onmousedown|onmouseup|onmousemove|onmouseout|onmouseover|' . 'onkeypress|onkeydown|onkeyup|javascript:';
    return stripslashes(preg_replace("/($bad_attributes)=\"(.*?)\"/is","", $inputHTML));
}
```

---

Test:

```
$html ='
<div id="teste"></div>
<p>
  <ul>
    <li onclick="fool()" onblur="fool()" class="some-class"></li>
    <li onblur="fool()"></li>
    <li onclick="fool()"></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</p>';

echo $sanitize->sanitizeHTML($html);
```

output:

```
<p>
  <ul>
    <li class="some-class"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</p>
```

> Good to remember there are certainly much better solutions for this situation
>   like to use an already tested sanitize class from a popular PHP
>   framework like CodeIgniter, CakePHP, Zend etc.

Hope it helps.